# listas haskell perimetro

Tags: haskell

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿podrían ayudarme a realizar esto?:

```
perimetro :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a] -> Float 
perimetro [] [] = 0.0
perimetro xt xs =
```

No sé cómo hacer para sacar el primero y el último elemento de cada lista al mismo tiempo para poder operarlos.

Comment: Hola Daniel, se bienvenido al sitio, es importante revises [ask] que te brinda información para realizar una buena pregunta, esta sea bien recibida en la comunidad y de esta forma obtengas buenas respuestas!.

Answer (score 0):

*Por favor, edita la pregunta y cambia el gráfico por texto. Facilitará la búsqueda posterior a quién pueda estar interesado en la pregunta.*

---

En haskell, las listas tienen una serie de métodos que ofrece el módulo `Data.List`, presentes sin más por estar importadas en el `Prelude`.

Así tienes:

- `head` y `tail` para obtener el primer elemento y el resto
- `init` y `last` para obtener los primeros elementos y el último

Por cómo están constituidas las listas como *listas enlazadas*, es preferible usar `head/tail` a `init/last` por eficiencia.

```
head :: [a] -> a
tail :: [a] -> [a]

init :: [a] -> [a] 
last :: [a] -> a
```

Dicho lo cual, la mejor manera de crear estos pares es usando las funciones `zip`:

```
zip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]
zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
```

Por ejemplo `zip (tail xs) xs` nos daría una lista de tuplas:
[(x<sub>1</sub>,x<sub>0</sub>), (x<sub>2</sub>,x<sub>1</sub>),...,(x<sub>n</sub>,x<sub>n-1</sub>)].

Con `zipWith (-) (tail xs) xs` haríamos la resta en un sólo paso: [(x<sub>1</sub>-x<sub>0</sub>), (x<sub>2</sub>-x<sub>1</sub>),...,(x<sub>n</sub>-x<sub>n-1</sub>)]

Pero aún nos faltaría cerrar el ciclo con la tupla (x<sub>0</sub>,x<sub>n</sub>). Basta con añadir el primer elemento al final, algo así: `zipWith (-) (tail xs ++ [head xs]) xs`

Lo mismo sería con la lista `ys`, y se volvería a aplicar `zip` para hacer el sumatorio. Poniendo las cosas en su sitio, sería algo así:

```
perimetro :: (Floating a) => [a] -> [a] -> a 
perimetro [] [] = 0.0
perimetro xs ys = sum [sqrt (i^2+j^2) | (i,j) <- zip xrs yrs]
    where
      rotl (z:zs) = zs ++ [z]
      xrs = zipWith (-) (rotl xs) xs
      yrs = zipWith (-) (rotl ys) ys
```